# Printing to a .gif file using GD::Graph. Permission denied while writing to file

Tags: perl, gd, permission-denied

I've written a page in PHP that takes user input and then I do a shell_exec to a Perl file after passing those parameters in.

My Perl file basically generates a GD::Graph. When I run the script for the first time, there seems to be no issue and I get a valid image.gif file. However, running it a second time, doesn't change any data on the image.gif file. It remains the same, as though it can't be over-written.

I then executed the Perl script via shell and passed the paramters manually. Here is the error message I get:

```
Failed to save graph to file: uploads/image.gif. Permission denied at image.pl line 178.
```

The relevant code in Perl is:

```
    my $bar_file = $filepath . '/image.gif';

    if (-e $bar_file) {
            #If file exists, delete
    unlink($bar_file);
    }
    else {
    print "File does not exist.";
    }

    open(IMG, ">$bar_file") 
      || die ("\nFailed to save graph to file: $bar_file. $!"); 

    binmode IMG; 
    print IMG $plot->gif(); 
    close IMG;
```

And the problematic line 178 is:

```
open(IMG, ">$bar_file")
```

I tried changing the file to CHMOD 777, but since its been generated by **Apache**, I do not have the sufficient permissions to CHMOD it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if unlink failed?
On success, it returns the number of files it successfully deleted. On failure, it returns false and sets $! (errno).

Comment: Hi Freek: The problem was with the .gif file permissions. What I did was when I create it, I CHMOD is to 775 within Perl, this way it allows re-write. Thanks for repyling though ..

Answer (score 0):

Surely you want to use the GD hooks in PHP itself?
http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php